# DB backups for Database per service

Tags: postgresql

I have a project built on a microservice architecture that uses the pattern: [database per service.](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) We are using two environments: stage and prod.
Once some prod bug occurs there are two ways (as I see it) to ask some developer to fix it:

1. Allow some developer access to prod and ask to fix the issue. Not looks good to me cause it is prod env :)
2. To do a prod dump of all databases, restore it on stage, do obfuscation, etc. Also looks not really simple to do regularly.

What approaches exist for solving such problems? Is there any pattern or approach allowing me to dump one specific user state in DB from production so that info can be inserted into another (stage) environment?

Comment: Dumping and restoring a single database is straightforward using `pg_dump`. Obfuscating the data will require more work from your side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any one general way to do this. I've worked with a variety of different approaches. They can all be correct, depending on your needs and the regulatory environment.

For example, if you have to comply with privacy laws, or SOX requirements, then you should never restore sensitive data on staging. Even if there's a way to do it with obfuscation, it's difficult to guarantee it works reliably every time, and difficult to explain to auditors.

There can also be practical reasons to avoid copying production data to staging. Staging is typically smaller capacity. If your production data is terabytes in size, it would be overkill and expensive to copy all of it (even obfuscated) to staging.

Sometimes you can use a logical data dump tool to export a sample of production data, and import that to staging. This solves the size issue, and you may be able to write dump filters to exclude sensitive data. Again, hard to guarantee it is done correctly every time.

Otherwise you could take a snapshot of the storage of the production database using LVM, or a physical database backup tool, and restore that snapshot on staging. Optionally applying obfuscation to the data on staging after restoring it.

In the most recent company where I worked with a microservices architecture like you describe, this is what we did. We had over 500 microservices with databases, and no reliable metadata about which data were sensitive. So the policy had to be simple and inflexible, to ensure compliance for the most sensitive possible case: **production data never leaves production servers.** Staging data had to be synthetic, used only for internal testing.

Comment: From your description looks like we're not the only one who has this challenge with db per service. Thank you for your answer, Bill.